# Cannot install packages from Nuget

Tags: vb.net, nuget

When I try to install packages I get this error:

```
Could not connect to the feed specified at "https://nuget.org/api/v2/"'.
 Please verify that the package source (located in the Package Manager Settings) is
 valid and ensure your network connectivity.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio 2017 then the source for nuget.org (the NuGet feed) is 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'.
Try changing your source path to that.  You can do that by selecting `Tools` -> `Options` from the main menu and then `NuGet Package Manager` -> `Package Sources`.
There you will see a list of sources, where you can add your own with the green arrow on the top right.

I'd recommend that you read the documentation on NuGet usage [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/upstream-sources?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav).

Comment: im using vs 2010